# Want to do some changes in the existing table that is created two days back

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I had created one table called PLANCESS two days back. Now i want to do some changes in the table using TOAD. How can i get back? What query should i use? FYI I am a beginner. Could you please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up the `alter table` statements in the documentation of Oracle (for example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001))

For the sake of it, you wouldn't refer to these types of statements as *queries* but as *ddls* (Data definition language).

Answer (score 0):

You can use alter query to make changes in your "PLANCESS" Table.

one another way is you just open the property box of your "PLANCESS" Table and you can edit from there also.

But property is only change in TOAD.

Write table name and press F4 you will get property window of that table.

Regards,
Chaitanya